# KVM: public bridge recieves IP on host, but VMs do not

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm

I've created br0 on the HOST with a single eth interface, it receives an IP and I can access it over ssh from other hosts in the network:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.50  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9ecf:6d35:bc82:c5e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1c:c4:47:ce:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 93667  bytes 23521427 (22.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31242  bytes 2603126 (2.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0     8000.001cc447ce72   yes     enp5s0f1
                            vnet0
                            vnet1
```

In KVM I've created the bridged network and assigned it to my VM:

```
# virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 host-bridge          active     yes           yes

# cat host-bridge.xml 
<network>
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

When I boot the VM (centos8, no FW) it does not receive any IP, dhclient times out, etc.

Any ideas what I'm missing? I've looked on the host firewall and I have a /24 allowance for the br0 interface for the home network.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup with some additional features such as bonding and vlans ending at bridges

```
# No special setting about KVM networking
virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes

# VM connected directly to host bridge
cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/MY_VM
...
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:xx:xx:xx:xx:40'/>
  <source bridge='br41'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
...

# And this might be your problem
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I know that `ip_forward` set to `TRUE` isn't best solution but you can use it to verify assumption and then you can elaborate your solution